# Increased output after capacitor has been added in parallel to the battery charger transformer

Tags: batteries, transformer, charger

What could be the cause of increase in voltage after polarized capacitor has been connected with a transformer? And what can I do to avoid that?

I added a capacitor in parallel with a transformer having 220V input and 14V output but it increased to 22V after the capacitor has been connected in parallel.

I really want to know what's the cause of this effect?

Comment: It increased from 14v to 22v even after the load(battery) has been connected

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What I meant was that, what could be the cause of increase in voltage after polarized capacitor has been connected with a transformer ? And what can I do to avoid that ? I added capacitor in parallel with a transformer having,220v input and 14v output but it increased to 22v after capacitor has been connected in parallel,I really want to know what's the cause of that effect ?

Comment: How did you measure the 14V? AC or DC? Is there a rectifier? Did you measure DC or AC, before or after rectifier? Where did you connect the capacitor, before rectifier or after rectifier? We can't guess what you are connecting and where.

Answer (score 2):

> *what could be the cause of increase in voltage after polarized
> capacitor has been connected in parallel with the battery charger
> transformer*

The capacitor hasn't been connected directly to the transformer; it's connected to the bridge rectifier output and, the bridge rectifier connects to the transformer. This is standard in this configuration; when you add the output capacitor, the DC voltage output level rises: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://learnabout-electronics.org/ac_theory/ac_waves02.php).

> *It increased from 14v to 22v even after the load(battery) has been
> connected*

Without the capacitor, the output level will be Vpk x 0.637. When you add the capacitor, it rises to nearly Vpk.